# Django call a Model method inside another method of the same Model (in models.py)?

Tags: python, django, django-models

**SOLVED BY JUST RESTARTING THE SERVER (`python manage.py runserver`)**

I want to call a model method inside another model method in *models.py* but i receive the error `AttributeError: module 'my_website.models' has no attribute 'my_model_method'`

Here is my model:

```py
class SaleCode(models.Model):
    #my fields and methods...

    #the method I want to call
    def generate_token(self, apply=True, length=5):
        # stuff
        return {
            "token": token,
            "self-applyed": apply
        }

    #save() method override
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            #self.code is one of my fields
            self.code = self.generate_token()["token"] #the line that generates the error
        super(SaleCode, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**What I have tried:**

- (As I read somewhere) I tried to place `@classmethod` *(and `@staticmethod`)* over the `generate_token(...)` declaration and then to call it as `SaleCode.generate_token()`:

```py
@classmethod
def generate_token(self, apply=True, length=5):
    ...

self.code = SaleCode.generate_token()["token"] #the line that generates the error
```

- I wrote the function outside the method and then called it as a normal function (it worked but it does not seem to be a "clear" way to do that.)

Comment: Your original solution should be working. You can call instance methods from other instance methods. Could you please `print(self)` in your `save()` as it looks like `self` isn't bound properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't know why but...

I just restarted the server and it worked.. really weird but know it works.